docker error when trying to access a Docker server using the TLS method (HTTPS) from local machine
I'm trying to securely connect to a Docker engine (Docker server) on my company's internal network. To ensure a safe connection, I'm using the TLS method (https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/protect-access), which encrypts communication between my local machine and the Docker engine. Both my computer and the Docker engine reside within the company's private network and aren't accessible from the public internet.
When i try to run docker commands from my local machine i get the following error:
error during connect: Get "https://$HOST:2376/v1.24/images/json": EOF
and when i try using the curl command:
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
I've tried with the DNS hostname and the IP address of the docker server for the $HOST.
Could someone please help me.
